# Cannot sign document with Crypt_GPG, fails with 'Cannot sign data. No passphrase provided.'

Tags: php, gnupg

I am using Crypt_GPG for PHP and I am unable to sign a GPG document even though I am importing a sign key which I just created, which does have a passphrase.

The code is pretty simple:

```
    $gpg = new \Crypt_GPG();

    // Import my private key and client public key
    $gpg->importKey($myPrivateKey);
    $gpg->importKey($clientPublicKey);

    $myPrivateFingerprint = $gpg->getKeys('my_email@example.org')[0]->getPrimaryKey()->getFingerprint();
    $clientPublicFingerprint = $gpg->getKeys('client@example.org')[0]->getPrimaryKey()->getFingerprint();

    $gpg->addSignKey($myPrivateFingerprint, 'myunittest');
    $gpg->addEncryptKey($clientPublicFingerprint);

    return $gpg->encryptAndSign('hello');
```

When I dump the Crypt_GPG class before the return statement I can see that the sign key is there as well as the passphrase. Here is the relevant portion:

```
 #signKeys: array:1 [
    "XXXXXXXXXXXXX" => array:2 [
      "fingerprint" => "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
      "passphrase" => "myunittest"
    ]
  ]
```

Everything matches up as it should. When I get to the final function, encryptAndSign(), it fails with this error:

```
[Crypt_GPG_BadPassphraseException] Cannot sign data. No passphrase provided.
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: `Crypt_GPG` relies on the underlying GPG implementation. What OS and gpg versions are you using?

Comment: Running in Docker: uname -r returns 4.9.49-moby.

Comment: gpg --version
gpg (GnuPG) 2.0.22
libgcrypt 1.5.3
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Home: ~/.gnupg
Supported algorithms:
Pubkey: RSA, ELG, DSA
Cipher: IDEA, 3DES, CAST5, BLOWFISH, AES, AES192, AES256, TWOFISH,
        CAMELLIA128, CAMELLIA192, CAMELLIA256
Hash: MD5, SHA1, RIPEMD160, SHA256, SHA384, SHA512, SHA224
Compression: Uncompressed, ZIP, ZLIB, BZIP2

Comment: My actual machine is Macbook Pro.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I did some research and it looks like there was a bug in the gpg version in Docker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you bishop. The problem seems to be a bug in gpg 2.0.22, which is the version I have in Docker. I did some testing and I noticed I had no issues on our qa and production servers. I checked the version on those boxes and it was 2.0.28. My code has been vindicated.

Comment: Excellent, glad you tracked it down. If you scan the `Crypt_GPG` code, you'll see it's littered with conditionals and workarounds for many different `gpg` versions. I'd suggest posting this over in their Issue Tracker, in case anyone else runs into it. Maybe they'll even add _yet another_ case to workaround gpg.